# How to name Haskell variables which in physics are uppercase

Tags: haskell, naming-conventions

Variable names in haskell need to be in small case, but

How to declare variables in .hs file, if we want to store **g** = 9.8 and **G** = 6.67300 × 10-11 (in following scenario) ?

Conventionally Physicists mention :

(1) Acceleration due to gravity on earth

**g** = 9.8 m/sec^2

(2) Universal Gravitational constant

**G** = 6.67300 × 10-11 m3 kg-1 s-2

Comment: You could implement some sort of handler that actually spits out your constants, perhaps even doing basic multiplication so that physicsConsts "gG" is g*G. Implementing a neat DSL might be just what the doctor ordered.

Comment: @Sarah: A "mathy" DSL would be really great. It would also be really cool if you could go from a formula string to a function: then you could embed relevant formulas verbatim--a good example of self-documenting code. I wonder how you could implement something like that in a type-safe way though. Having units enforced by the type system would be awesome too; I remember reading about F# doing something like that.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: talk about overkill LOL

Comment: BTW, @Optimight, is your question focused on the naming of the variables, or on the best way to write the expressions which evaluates to the actual constants?

Comment: @Riccardo My question is focused on the naming of the variable. And definitely, I would also like to know the best way to write the expressions which evaluates to the actual constant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will just have to come up with another name. The distinction between names starting with upper- and lowercase letters is part of the syntax.

While this may be unfortunate in your case, it's a design trade-off. In order to simplify differentiating between different things (e.g. between variables and constructors), identifiers starting with lowercase letters and ones starting with uppercase letters are fundamentally different.

Answer (score 11):

You could give them meaningful names. Just because mathematicians and physicists historically liked to use inscrutable symbols with no way of interpreting them other than rote memorisation doesn't mean you have to. We're typing now, not writing long-hand, so defining equations in terms of `earthGravity` and `gravitationalConstant` isn't so much harder to write than in terms of `g` and `G`, and it's a hell of a lot easier to read!

Or, you could designate that all identifiers prefixed with something like `c` represent standard well known constants, and use `cg` and `cG`.

Comment: I don't know: reading a *formula* with well-known single-letter names is easier than reading the same formula with long form names. It's just much easier to see the whole formula at a glance with shorter names than it is with names like `earthGravity`.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis True, I'm being a little disingenuous. Given that the single-symbols names already exist and *are* well-known, the traditional names are a bit easier to read. But if all code were written that way, it would be unintelligible. Ever seen a program written in APL?

Comment: physicists and mathematicians not seldomly have to deal with formulae that are more than a line long even with one letter variable names. They know their variable names, so full english names for every variable is in fact way harder to read in most cases

Answer (score 3):

I would simply use `g` and `_G`. I think the underscore isn't too distracting.

Comment: It would however interact with GHC's mechanism for unused variable warnings - names beginning with an underscore are ignored.